# Running a GUI client multiple times without having to close it

Tags: java, swing

I'm in the process of making a GUI where I input a string into a text box and, once I click a Jbutton, a second text box will produce the string I inputted into the first or produce a random string from a method I created (public void associate()). When I run the GUI and click the button to produce the text in the second text box, everything works fine. However, when I click the button a second time so the GUI performs the same action, nothing happens. Is there anything I can do so that I don't have to close the GUI every time I wish to run it multiple times?

```
public class GUIWindow extends JFrame {
private Joketeller robot= new Joketeller();
private JLabel speakerlabel = new JLabel("Joke");
private JLabel MarcoLabel= new JLabel ("Marco");
private JTextField speakerfield= new JTextField ("Enter Joke Here");
private JTextField Marcofield= new JTextField ("",20);
private JButton Jokebutton=new JButton("Recite Joke >>>");

public GUIWindow()  {
    JPanel dataPanel= new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,2,12,16));
    dataPanel.add(speakerlabel);
    dataPanel.add(MarcoLabel);
    dataPanel.add(speakerfield);
    dataPanel.add(Marcofield);

    JPanel buttonPanel= new JPanel();
    buttonPanel.add(Jokebutton);
    Container container = getContentPane();
    container.add(dataPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    container.add(buttonPanel,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    Jokebutton.addActionListener(new JokeListener());
}

    private class JokeListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String input=speakerfield.getText();
        if (Jokebutton.isEnabled()) {
        robot.setJoke(input);
        String Response= robot.getResponse();
        Marcofield.setText(Response);}
```

Joketeller class:

```
public class Joketeller {


    private static String Marco;
    private static String Response;
    static int i= (int)(Math.random()*((5-1)+1)+1);
    static String r;

    public void setMarco(String Joke ) {
        Marco=Joke;
    }

    public void setJoke(String Joke) {
        Marco=Joke;
        associate();

    }


    public String getJoke() {
        return Marco;
    }

    public static String getMarco() {
        return Marco;
    }

        public static void associate(){
        if(i==1) 
            r= "Connect Angie";
        else if(i==2)
            r= "*Cloud Laugh*";
        else if(i==3)
            r= "Community";
        else if(i==4)
            r=getMarco();
        else if(i==5)
            r= "Indeed!";
        Response=r;

        }

    public String getResponse() {
        return Response;
    }

    }
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Please follow Java naming conventions : packages, attributes, variables, parameters, method have to start in **lowerCase**, while class, interface should start in **UpperCase**

Comment: Well, since `i` never changes, why would expect anything else to change

Answer (score 2):

The first thing that jumps out at me, is the overuse of `static`...

```
public class Joketeller {


    private static String Marco;
    private static String Response;
    static int i= (int)(Math.random()*((5-1)+1)+1);
    static String r;
```

This is not helping your here, and if done right, shouldn't be needed.

The next issue is with `i`...

```
    static int i = (int) (Math.random() * ((5 - 1) + 1) + 1);

    public static void associate() {
        if (i == 1) {
            r = "Connect Angie";
        } else if (i == 2) {
            r = "*Cloud Laugh*";
        } else if (i == 3) {
            r = "Community";
        } else if (i == 4) {
            r = getMarco();
        } else if (i == 5) {
            r = "Indeed!";
        }
        Response = r;

    }
```

`i` is never changed. Because it's `static`, you can create as many instance of `Joketeller` as you like and it will need change, so the response will always be the same.

While there are a number of possible ways to fix it, the simplest would be to remove all the `static` and make `i` a local variable within `associate`, as it's really not used anywhere else..

```
public void associate() {
    int rnd = (int) (Math.random() * ((5 - 1) + 1) + 1);
    if (rnd == 1) {
        r = "Connect Angie";
    } else if (rnd == 2) {
        r = "*Cloud Laugh*";
    } else if (rnd == 3) {
        r = "Community";
    } else if (rnd == 4) {
        r = getMarco();
    } else if (rnd == 5) {
        r = "Indeed!";
    }
    response = r;

}
```

This means you don't need to create a new instance of `Joketeller` in order to get a different response.

For example....

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class GUIWindow extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                GUIWindow wnd = new GUIWindow();
                wnd.pack();
                wnd.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                wnd.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private Joketeller robot = new Joketeller();
    private JLabel speakerlabel = new JLabel("Joke");
    private JLabel marcoLabel = new JLabel("Marco");
    private JTextField speakerfield = new JTextField("Enter Joke Here");
    private JTextField marcofield = new JTextField("", 20);
    private JButton jokebutton = new JButton("Recite Joke >>>");

    public GUIWindow() {
        JPanel dataPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 2, 12, 16));
        dataPanel.add(speakerlabel);
        dataPanel.add(marcoLabel);
        dataPanel.add(speakerfield);
        dataPanel.add(marcofield);

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.add(jokebutton);
        Container container = getContentPane();
        container.add(dataPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        container.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        jokebutton.addActionListener(new JokeListener());
    }

    private class JokeListener implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String input = speakerfield.getText();
            if (jokebutton.isEnabled()) {
                robot.setJoke(input);
                String Response = robot.getResponse();
                marcofield.setText(Response);
            }
        }
    }

    public class Joketeller {

        private String marco;
        private String response;
        private String r;

        public void setMarco(String Joke) {
            marco = Joke;
        }

        public void setJoke(String Joke) {
            marco = Joke;
            associate();

        }

        public String getJoke() {
            return marco;
        }

        public String getMarco() {
            return marco;
        }

        public void associate() {
            int rnd = (int) (Math.random() * ((5 - 1) + 1) + 1);
            if (rnd == 1) {
                r = "Connect Angie";
            } else if (rnd == 2) {
                r = "*Cloud Laugh*";
            } else if (rnd == 3) {
                r = "Community";
            } else if (rnd == 4) {
                r = getMarco();
            } else if (rnd == 5) {
                r = "Indeed!";
            }
            response = r;

        }

        public String getResponse() {
            return response;
        }

    }

}
```